# Why am I getting "Segmentation faults" when trying to insert elements in doubly linked list with header? C language

Tags: c, header, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

Edit 1: Forgot to translate some stuff to English. Now fixed.
Edit 2: HEADER instance.

I'm starting my studies on doubly linked lists, and I've been having a problem to insert items at the beginning or at the end of my list.

IMPORTANT: I'm using a header to do that. It's important to do it with this, because the usual insert is already mastered.

Thanks!

Function to insert at the beginning:

```
void beginning_insert(ELEMENT *list, HEADER *l, int value)
{
    ELEMENT * p = malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));
    p -> info = value;
    p -> next = l -> head;
    p -> previous = NULL;
    l -> head = p;
    if(l -> tail == NULL)
    {
        l -> tail = l -> head;
    }
    else
    {
        (((l -> head) -> next) -> previous) = p;
    }
    l -> number_of_nodes++;

    list = p;
}
```

Function to insert at the end:

```
ELEMENT * end_insert(HEADER *l, int value)
{
    ELEMENT * new = malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));
    new -> info = valor;
    new -> next = NULL;
    new -> previous = l -> tail;
    if(l-> head == NULL)
    {
        l -> head = new;
    }
    else
    {
        l -> tail -> next = new;    
    }
    l -> tail = new;
    l -> number_of_nodes++;


    return new;
}
```

Structs used:

```
typedef struct element
{
    int info;
    struct element * next;//control
    struct element * previous;//control

} ELEMENT;

typedef struct header   //control
{
    ELEMENT * head;
    int number_of_nodes;
    ELEMENT * tail;

} HEADER;


//Header instance
HEADER * start_header()
{
    HEADER *l;
    l = malloc(sizeof(HEADER));

    l -> number_of_nodes = 0;
    l -> head = NULL;
    l -> tail = NULL;

    return l;
}
```

Comment: step through in your debugger...

Comment: Show us how the HEADER instance is initialized.

Comment: Did you initialize `head` and `tail` to NULL in your header?

Comment: `(((l -> head) -> prox) -> ant)` what is this? what is `prox` ?

Comment: @paddy It's there, I edited the question.

Comment: `list = p;` in `beginning_insert()` does nothing.  Show how `beginning_insert()` would be called.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine - [Demo](https://ideone.com/tFWbbt). Are you sure you have posted the code that you are compiling? It seems you made some changes before posting.

Comment: In main, it'd be called `...list = beginning_insert(list,header,value);...`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I'm pretty sure I'm compiling this code. It's been a pain in the neck to me, but it is really not working.

Comment: Did you see the demo I commented? I think the only thing to check now would be your main. Can you post that too? (Relevant parts).

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I've just seen it. The problem was really a beginner problem. I hadn't initialized my header as a pointer. That was it. Thks for the help.

Comment: Also, check the return value from `malloc`. If it cannot allocate memory on the heap, it will return NULL. In that case your code will definitely give a SEGFAULT

Comment: `list = p; in beginning_insert()` does not affect  `list` in `beginning_insert(list,header,value);`  Suggest `void beginning_insert(ELEMENT *list, HEADER *l, int value)` --> `ELEMENT * beginning_insert(HEADER *l, int value)` and _return_ `p`.

Comment: Also for getting the value of `list` in the caller, return `ELEMENT*` and return `p`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya You mean as I've done in `end_insert(..)`?

Comment: Yes. Just like `end_insert`.

Comment: A general advice - Enable all compiler warnings. The problem you were having could have been easily seen as a  warning.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Thanks a lot for the advice. I'll do that from now on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
Code works fine, problem when calling

```
HEADER * header = start_header();
```

Previously, it was being done the wrong way:
`HEADER header = start_header();`

Answer (score 0):

For a better understanding of a doubly linked list I suggest you to avoid the usage of a header.

Instead, you should use stuff like this

```
ELEMENT* go_start(ELEMENT* l)
{
      while (l->prev)
          l = l->prev;
      return l;
}

ELEMENT* go_end(ELEMENT* l)
{
      while (l->next)
          l = l->next;
      return l;
}
```

As soon as this make sense to you, you should be able to easily push a new elem.

And your main should stay very simple, no malloc in it:

```
int main()
{
     ELEMENT* list;

     list = push_top(list, 18);
     list = push_bottom(list, 18);
     list = push_top(list, 18);

     list = go_start(list);

     while (l->next)
     {
          printf("%d\n", l.info);
     }

     return (count_elem(list));
}
```

If you can run this main and got the expected output, your understanding of linked list should be good ;)

Have fun,

PS: your seg fault probably comes from your else condition. You are probably going too far with your pointers.

Comment: Thks for the tips. I've actually managed to understand the doubly linked lists quite well, by myself. But the next step is really to do it by using a header.

Comment: while() loop doesn't loop.